# SQL Statement (Insert /Join / Union All???)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Morning All,

I have two web forms (WeeklyAgenda & MonthlyAgenda) that holds minutes of meetings that are both seperate tables in my database. These web pages also enables users to add actions to an action table within my database.

The minutes of meeting and actions both have a seperate button assigned to them when updating data. The Actions area enables a user to add three fields only (Action, Owner and Targetdate).

My Actions table has additional columns (AgendaID, AgendaDate, AgendaTypeDescription and ActionStatusID) that i would like to populate. These Additional columns are already available on the web page as they are part of the agenda form which the user has already filled out.

Instead of adding these fields again to my action area and getting the user to add these again, i want to save myself and Joe Bloggs time by trying to take these fields (AgendaID, AgendaDate, AgendaTypeDescription and ActionStatusID) that have already been added two one of the agenda tables and to extract them and import them somehow with the remaining fields (Action, Owner and Targetdate) and add these to the action table.

Essentially the data is already there but spread accross three tables.

I have been trying to make a join between these tables in a stored procedure to that thies extra fileds are inserted to the Actions table.

Im not too sure how to complete this and have tried Joins and UNION all but not managed to get this working?

I know that i need to join AgendaID, AgendaDate and AgendaTypeDescription from both the WeeklyAgenda table and the MonthlyAgenda table.

This is my code so far for the action table stored procedure (That works without the additional fields)...

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add_Action_Insert]
     @ActionID INT OUTPUT,
@Action VARCHAR(MAX),
     @Owner VARCHAR(50),
     @TargetDate DATETIME
 AS
 INSERT INTO Action (
                    Action,
          Owner,
               TargetDate)                  
    VALUES (
        @Action,
        @Owner,
        @TargetDate)
    SELECT @ActionID = scope_identity()
```

This is what i want to change it to...

```
   Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add_Action_Insert_Test]
     @ActionID INT OUTPUT,
@AgendaID INT,
@AgendaDate DATETIME,
@AgendaTypeDescription VARCHAR(50),
@Action VARCHAR(MAX),
     @Owner VARCHAR(50),
     @TargetDate DATETIME,
@ActionStatusID INT
  AS
  INSERT INTO Action (
        AgendaID,
        AgendaDate,
        AgendaTypeDescription,
        Action,
        Owner,
        TargetDate,
        ActionStatusID)                 
    VALUES (
        @AgendaID,
        @AgendaDate,
        @AgendaTypeDescription,
        @Action,
        @Owner,
        @TargetDate,
        @ActionStatusID)
    SELECT @ActionID = scope_identity()
```

This is an image of what data i have in the database now...
[image: What i currently have]

This is an image of what i would like in my database...
[image: What i would like to achieve]

I appriechiate any information and help that i get.  Im just unsure if i need to Insert this additional information from the other two tanles or to make a join???

Many Thanks in advance.
Betty

Comment: It would help if you could also include structures for WeeklyAgenda and MonthlyAgenda, along with examples of the rows you would like to use for populating the empty columns in Action for ActionID=23.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are distributing the *AgendaDate* and *AgendaTypeDescription* columns also to the *Action* table. These two columns should rather remain in the *Agenda* tables only. Then, when retrieving data from the *Action* table, you would join the *Agenda* tables like this:

```
SELECT ac.AgendaID, ag.AgendaDate, ag.AgendaTypeDescription, ag.Action, ac.Ownder, ac.TargetDate
 FROM MonthlyAgenda AS ag
 JOIN Action AS ac ON ag.AgendaID = ac.AgendaID
UNION
SELECT ac.AgendaID, ag.AgendaDate, ag.AgendaTypeDescription, ag.Action, ac.Ownder, ac.TargetDate
 FROM WeeklyAgenda AS ag
 JOIN Action AS ac ON ag.AgendaID = ac.AgendaID
```

If you decide to keek the *AgendaDate* and *AgendaTypeDescription* in the *Action* table, you need at least to add a parameter *@AgendaID* to the Add_Action_Insert_Test procedure to identify which agenda the action belongs to.

Then your procedure would look like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add_Action_Insert_Test] 
  @ActionID INT OUTPUT, 
  @AgendaID INT, 
  @Action VARCHAR(MAX), 
  @Owner VARCHAR(50), 
  @TargetDate DATETIME, 
  @ActionStatusID INT 
AS 
INSERT INTO Action ( 
    AgendaID, 
    AgendaDate, 
    AgendaTypeDescription, 
    Action, 
    Owner, 
    TargetDate, 
    ActionStatusID)                  
SELECT
    @AgendaID,
    AgendaDate,
    AgendaTypeDescription,
    @Action, 
    @Owner, 
    @TargetDate, 
    @ActionStatusID
FROM MonthlyAgenda WHERE AgendaID = @AgendaID
UNION
SELECT
    @AgendaID,
    AgendaDate,
    AgendaTypeDescription,
    @Action, 
    @Owner, 
    @TargetDate, 
    @ActionStatusID
FROM WeeklyAgenda WHERE AgendaID = @AgendaID

SELECT @ActionID = scope_identity()
```

In this example, I assume that values of the *AgendaIDs* within *WeeklyAgenda* and *MonthlyAgenda* are disjunctive. It means that any *AgendaID* from the *WeeklyAgenda* cannot occur within *MonthlyAgenda* and vice versa. You can achiecve it e.g. by using even IDs in one table and odd IDs in the another table (using some advanced settigns on IDENTITY properties of the columns).